# Destroy an object does not destroy associated objects using rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following Model

```
class Will < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :product
  has_one :willFamilyDetail, :dependent => :destroy
  has_one :childCompensate, :dependent => :destroy
  has_one :wifeCompensate, :dependent => :destroy
  has_one :willDebt, :dependent => :destroy
  has_one :willLegalHeirBequest, :dependent => :destroy
  has_one :willGrandchildrenBequest, :dependent => :destroy
  has_one :willBequestOther, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

and all other models have belongs_to.
When I use Rails console to delete the Will object, other objects still appear in the database, they must get destroyed right?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Tip perhaps unrelated to your bug: ActiveRecord association symbols should be snake case, not camel case.

Comment: How are you verifying that the records are still in the database? It could be that they just exist in memory.

Comment: @MarkMerritt I use Rails console to verify like WillDebt.all, it returns the record that should be deleted, any advice?

Comment: @JakeWorth converting the association symbols to snake case solved it, please write it as an answer to accept it. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ActiveRecord association symbols must be snake case, not camel case, following Ruby convention. Converting each association name from camel case to snake case (`:willFamilyDetail` to `:will_family_detail`, etc.) solves the issue.